# Structure a DynamoDB table to perform simultaneous equality tests in a query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have very specific access patterns on a DynamoDB table and I am trying to learn what is the best way to structure the table for my use case. I would like to understand how DynamoDB should be used when having multiple equality tests in the same query.

Desired Query (one query with all of the following constraints):

- several equality tests: Place, Device, MeasurementType, SampleTimeResolution.
- range (assume I only use *begins_with*): ordered measurements in a specific day. So the Sort Key seems trivial to me: Date in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.

---

My question is how I should choose my Partition Key. So far I came up with three options:

1. Partition Key is the concatenation of all my equality test attributes. It would look like this: "xxxxxxxxx:yyyyyyyyy:wwwwwwwww:zzzz" (format: Place:Device:MeasurementType:SampleTimeResolution). This Partition Key will be repeated at least 12 times and up to 70000 times in the table.

   - Pros: 1) I am sure that what I want to query is in the same partition; 2) I know that data would be uniformelly distributed.
   - Cons: it doesn't appear natural or readable to me, so I don't know if this would be a good practice.
2. Partition Key is the concatenation of Device and MeasurementType. It would look like this: "xxxxxxxxx:wwwwwwwww" (format: Device:MeasurementType). This Partition Key will be repeated around 71000 times in the table.

   - Pros: I know that data would be uniformelly distributed.
   - Cons: 1) I am not completely sure that what I want to query is in the same partition (but it will most likely be); 2) it doesn't appear natural or readable to me, so I don't know if this would be a good practice.
3. Partition Key is the Device. This is the attribute with the most uniform distribution across the data set and I want to query it by equality. Each Partition Key (Device) will be repeated at least 88000 times and up to 800000 times in the table.

   - Pros: readable
   - Cons: 1) don't know if what I want to query will be in the same partitiion; 2) not sure if queries will be as fast as Option 1); 3) I don't know how good DynamoDB is at querying multiple attributes (that are not part of the key).

I don't have experience with DynamoDB, so I am very thankful for your feedback!

Comment: Yes, the key choice is the key thing! I would worry about case (1) resulting in hot keys, case (2) should be workable as should case(3). I would, without in depth understanding, consider case 2, and use a Local Secondary Index to help to provide insight into the inequalities you want to use?

Comment: @Henry thank you for the feedback. From what I understood after reading about LSIs, they are intended for alternative queries. What I mean by this is that you should use them when you have multiple Access Patterns, so you want to do 2 different specific queries very often. You design your table for one pattern and then use an LSI for another pattern. Is this correct? If so, I don't see any advantage on using LSI in  my case, since I only have one Access Pattern

Comment: True, but it might be a simple way to filter on the equalities whilst preventing hot keys? I've nt had to do a lot of DynamoDB structuring before, so it's relatively new to me, but that's my gut instinct